# Docker's behavior when mounting volumes

Tags: docker, containers

I'm currently trying to understand how Docker handles mounting of volumes and ran into the following behavior which seems kind of stange to me:

Assumed that we want to mount the /var/run directory into a container (just as an example), we do the following:

```
$ docker run -i -t -v /var/run:/test ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

So far, everything works fine and all the folders and files residing under /var/run show up inside the container within /test.

Now see what happens if we decide to mount the /var directory:

```
$ docker run -i -t -v /var:/test ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

Still, all the host folders within /var show up inside /test. However, after cd into /test/run, the files and directories from the host are not displayed. In other words, Docker not seems to do a 'recursive' mount of subsequent child directories and their content. Is this ordinary Docker behavior?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem and it is not expected behaviour. What version of docker are you using (and on which os)?

Comment: I'm running latest Docker 1.12 on Debian Jessie VM in Virtualbox

Comment: The first command e.g. enables me to see docker.sock inside the launched container, while the second only shows the container's directories under /run dir.

Comment: Got it. Didn't get you before. Interesting...

Comment: explanation is here: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-March/150031.html (/run is now a tmpfs, and /var/run is bind mounted to it.) i'm still exploring this topic...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not just ordinary Docker behavior; that's ordinary *linux* behavior. When you bind-mount a filesystem onto another directory, as in:

```
mkdir /tmp/mount
mount -o bind /var /tmp/mount
```

You will only see files in the destination mount that exist *in the source filesystem*.  You will not see the files contained in any child mounts unless you were to explicitly bind mount those directories as well:

```
mount -o bind /var/run /tmp/mount/run
```

This is exactly the behavior you see with Docker because this is exactly the same mechanism Docker uses to expose host directories inside your containers.

Comment: Yet another thing I learned about Linux. Thank you very much!

Comment: is there a way to explicitly have docker get those mounts as well?